# NextJS 13 RouteHandler Request Invalid JSON

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

Currently using the next Next.JS 13 [Route Handler](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/routing/route-handlers#request-body) to process information passed by a form. And I'm trying to figure out why I can't get the new Route Handler to function despite mirroring the doc (above link) code.

`/app/contactForm/route.ts`

```
export async function POST( request: Request) {
    console.log('Body', request.body)
    const res = await request.json();
    ...
}
```

But when trying to process the request data, I get an error:

```
Body ReadableStream { locked: false, state: 'readable', supportsBYOB: false }
error - SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'd', "dqaf=ll" is not valid JSON
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at parseJSONFromBytes (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6444:19)
    at successSteps (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6418:27)
    at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:1133:60
    at node:internal/process/task_queues:140:7
    at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:204:9)
    at AsyncResource.runMicrotask (node:internal/process/task_queues:137:8)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

Request raw body sent by postman:
`dqaf=ll`

bodyParser is `true`

I rewrote the handler as an api route in `/pages/api/contactForm.js` (and removed the route handler to prevent conflicts) and that seems to work:

```
export default function handler(req, res) {
    const body = req.body
    console.log('body: ', body)
}
```

Logs:

```
body:  dqaf=ll
```

Am I doing something incorrectly in the route handler?

I've tried turning off the bodyParser by including the following code in `/app/contactForm/route.ts` but I still get the same syntax error:

```
export const config = {
    api: {
        bodyParser: false,
    }
}
```

Logs:

```
error - SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'd', "dqaf=ll" is not valid JSON
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at parseJSONFromBytes (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6444:19)
    at successSteps (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6418:27)
    at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:1133:60
    at node:internal/process/task_queues:140:7
    at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:204:9)
    at AsyncResource.runMicrotask (node:internal/process/task_queues:137:8)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

I will end up using the `/pages/api` format of handling routes for now, but trying to understand if I am missing something from the route handler, or if this is a bug with new nextjs 13?

Answer (score 0):

I found something that might work.

Looks like there is at least one [related issue on github](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/48403)

I took this from the GitHub issue and used querystring because `JSON.parse(string);` didn't work for me.

```
  import { parse } from "querystring";

.....

  const input = await request.body!.getReader().read();
  const decoder = new TextDecoder();
  const string = decoder.decode(input.value);
  const body = parse(string);
```